# What is this syntax CSS (&:after, nested selectors ...)

Tags: css, syntax

I've never seen this type of syntax beforce in css , does anyone know how can i find some documentation on it or can explain it ? I did some research but I don't even know what I'm looking for.

```
.active{

  a{
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1.3, 1.3, 1.3);
    transform: scale3d(1.3, 1.3, 1.3);

    &:after{
      height: 100%;
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: i believe that is sass/scss

Comment: indeed thank you , i copied it on google but i found nothing , thanks

Comment: well, does anyone know why my post is still downvoted? I applied all of the advices in the guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a preprocessor language like `sass` or `less`. It makes you able to write with the syntax you write there and the it's being processed to correct css. See more here https://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/

Answer (score 1):

Thats `sass`, a css extension language.
You can find the documentation here - http://sass-lang.com/